# JSON Restful service. Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, rest, json.net

I have a problem serializing and deserializing json. I have searched for an answer and although Ive seen the same problem elsewhere, non of the answers have helped me. I'm having the same problem using newtonsoft or the javascriptserializer.

My web method in the rest service

```
[OperationContract(Name="Customers")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "json/Customer/Read/{CustomerID}/{CustomerCode}/{ParentCustomerID}/{CustomerName}")]
String JSONReadCustomers(String CustomerID, String CustomerCode, String ParentCustomerID, String CustomerName);
```

The class

```
public class Customer
{
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    public String CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Customer(DataRow DR)
    {
        CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(DR["CustomerID"]);
        CustomerCode = (DR["CustomerCode"] != null) ? DR["CustomerCode"].ToString() : "";
        CustomerName = (DR["CustomerName"] != null) ? DR["CustomerName"].ToString() : "";
    }
}
```

the bit that actually does the serializatiion

```
private String GetJSON(DataTable DT)
{
    try
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
        {
            customers.Add(new Customer(DR));
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

So far everything seems ok.
The service compiles and runs ok. when I test it in a browser I get the following result

```
"[{\"CustomerID\":1,\"CustomerCode\":\"AMT-1\",\"CustomerName\":\".AMTDisp\"},{\"CustomerID\":2,\"CustomerCode\":\"COM-2\",\"CustomerName\":\".ComexDisp,_\"}]"
```

I have a VB test harness that I am using call the rest service and deserialize the returned json

The Class

```
Public Class Customer
    Public CustomerID As Int32
    Public CustomerCode As String
    Public CustomerName As String
End Class
```

the method

```
Private Function DeserializeJSON() As List(Of Customer)

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(GetCustomerURL())
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseJSON As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Dim customers As List(Of Customer) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Customer))(responseJSON)
    Return customers

End Function
```

The Error

```
{"Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RESTTestHarness.Customer]."}
```

I have used a variety of different ways such as setting the bodystyle to Wrapped and having a root object. Nothing seems to work. I always get the same error. I believe the error is really simple here, but I just can't see it now.

Comment: I notice in your test harness Customer class, you just have instance level members, not public properties, like in your Customer class in your method. Can you change your test harness class to use public properties `get;set;`? and see what happens?

Comment: I did try this but had the same problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to return a generic json response, you need to change your service operation contract to return a Message not a string,

your service operation implementation should then look something like:

```
public System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message CreateJsonResponse()
{
  List<Customer> response = GetCustomers(); 

  string msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

  return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(msg, "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Ismail. I'm on my way home So ill look at it in the Morning.